# Uncaught TypeError: myModule.function is not a function

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm unable to call a function that is defined in a module if I load the module through define, however when I require the module the function exists and can be called.  So something like this

Calling module

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    ... ,
    "app/myModule"

], function (declare, ... , myModule) {

        var thisModule = declare(null, {

            constructor: function () {

            }
        });

        /**
         * Go to next page
         */
        thisModule.nextPage = function () {

            myModule.goToPage(nextPage).then(function(){

            });
        };

        return thisModule;
});
```

Called module

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare"
],

function (declare) {

    var myModule = declare(null, {

        constructor: function () {

        }
    });

    myModule.goToPage = function(page){

        var deferred = new Deferred();

        //some code

        deferred.resolve(1);

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return  myModule;

});
```

And I get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: myModule.goToPage is not a function

However if I put a require around the code and require myModule it works and the function exists on the myModule object

Like this

```
thisModule.nextPage = function () {

     require("app/myModule", function(myModule){

        myModule.goToPage(nextPage).then(function(){                
        });

    });         
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem surly is the order of your define imports , the `myModule` is refering to other loaded module in the define , so to be sur that it was the case , put your module just after declare , in both `define` and `calback` function like bellow :

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "app/myModule",
    ...

], function (declare,myModule, ... ) {
    ....
})
```

Comment: does this fix the issue ? otherwise please post the whole code to check again :)

Comment: Ok, I did as you suggested, and moved the module to the very beginning, after declare, however that did not resolve the issue, it could not find the function.  I may need to rewrite the module, I was trying to make static methods (so I didn't have to create new instance each time I used the module in other location in my code)  which could be the reason they are not working.  Still researching.

Comment: mmm , that's weird , do you use require for the calling module ?

Comment: Then , when you use use the calling module and How ?

Comment: it gets used in a custom widget, and is included at the top using define, and is present in the function parameter.  Then in the Custom widget I have a function that uses it, it just calls thisModule.NextPage, that part works fine.

Comment: its strange because there's another module that uses it earlier on in execution before this happens, and it calls the function no problem.  I remember having a similar issue before and I had to use exports to resolve a circular dependency (which cased this exact same error) .So I checked all the modules I'm loading I found one inside myModule, that is using myModule so I think that is the circular dependency that I have to fix.

Comment: Sorry one more note, found this post which sounds like a similar issue, with define vs require http://stackoverflow.com/q/32045101

Comment: I dont think it's a circular isuse because there is no refernce of the calling module in the called  . ( you only refer the "app/myModule" in the calling )